# How to make a word mentioned in column A bold in column B where that word is mentioned in a sentence (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

Basically, I am trying to create conditional formatting that does the following:
[Simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcCmh.png)
I really would like to just make bold a word (not a whole sentence) in column B that is mentioned in column A.

I tried many different formulas in the "Value or formula" field:

1. `=REGEXMATCH($B1,A1)`
2. `=REGEXMATCH($B1,"<"&A1&">")`
3. `=REGEXMATCH(B1,"\b"&A1&"\b")`
4. `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(B1," "),"\b"&A1&"\b"))`
   ...but none of these work.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to partially format a cell with conditional formatting

Comment: Thank you a lot, @Martín, for confirmation. I assumed the same thing but wasn't 100% sure. Do you think it can be done in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually *sort of* possible, if you are willing to stretch your definition of 'bold'. It's absolutely right that you can't make a particular part of a text string within a cell bold (or italic/underlined/coloured/etc.) in a way that replicates the effect if you manually select an area of a text string and format it using the menu bar options - effectively you are setting some metadata which sits 'outside' of the cell so isn't accessible to a formula.

*However*, Unicode fonts generally contain a region within their character map which corresponds to a bold version of the underlying font, and so with a little bit of trickery it's possible to substitute characters with their bold version. Here's a formula which achieves something like your original request:

```
=let(wordstobold,A1:A2,
     sentencestosplit,B1:B2,
     boldwords,map(wordstobold,lambda(eachword,concatenate(map(split(regexreplace(eachword,"(.)","$1_"),"_"),lambda(eachchar,filter(BOLDCHARS(),exact(STDCHARS(),eachchar))))))),
     splitsentences,map(sentencestosplit,wordstobold,lambda(sentence,word,split(sentence,word,false))),
     presplits,choosecols(splitsentences,1),
     postsplits,choosecols(splitsentences,2),
     map(presplits,boldwords,postsplits,lambda(x,y,z,x&y&z)))
```

The formula exploits the fact that SPLIT treats a multicharacter delimiter as a single entity by default, so if you pass the word to be bolded to SPLIT as the delimiter for the sentence it will split the sentence into two halves, presplit and postsplit. The substitution of the normal characters for bold characters could be done in a number of ways, but what I'm doing here is to explode the word to be bolded into individual characters and then MAPping a the equivalent bold character onto each one using FILTER/EXACT.

A couple of 'helper' Named Functions are required: `STDCHARS()` & `BOLDCHARS()`; these don't accept any parameters and are a means of storing the character sets for the part of the formula which swaps characters for their bold equivalents. It would be possible to integrate these into the formula, albeit at the expense of readability.

`STDCHARS()`:

```
={"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h";"i";"j";"k";"l";"m";"n";"o";"p";"q";"r";"s";"t";"u";"v";"w";"x";"y";"z";"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z";"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"}
```

`BOLDCHARS()`:

```
={"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";""}
```